# MYSQL Join WHERE Two dates column between two dates column

Tags: mysql

I have question about SQL command. Simplify - My first table looks like this:

```
    ID      EAN      DATE_FROM     DATE_TO      PRICE

    1      123456    2020-01-01    2020-02-15    10
    2      456789    2020-02-05    2020-02-15    20
    3      987654    2020-01-10    2020-03-01    30
    4      123456    2020-02-15    2020-02-17    25
```

And my second table look like this:

```
    ID      EAN       DATE_FROM      DATE_TO      TYPE       DEALER

    1      123456    2019-11-01    2020-02-15     APPLE     RandomName1
    2      456789    2020-01-04    2020-03-20     BANANA    RandomName2
    3      987654    2020-01-10    2020-03-01     ORANGE    RandomName3
    4      123456    2019-11-01    2020-02-17     MANGO     RandomName4
```

And what I am doing and what I want..

I want to JOIN data from table 2 (type and dealer) with data from table 1.
So results will looks like table 2 but with date_from and date_to from table 1 and price from table 1.

Here is my SQL - But query bad joins date_from and date_to. Doesnt not show all ean from table 1 if I am joining it from table 2.

```
SELECT t1.ean, t1.date_from, t1.date_to, t1.price, t2.type, t2.dealer
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
table2 t2
ON t1.ean = t2.ean
AND t1.date_from >= t2.date_from
AND t1.date_to <= t2.date_to
```

How to do join better way if I am need to join two dates columns between two dates columns ?

EDIT:

Why I am need join on dates ? Because Dealer is changing between dates.
EAN 123456 is from 2020-01-01 to 2020-02-15 on first trader (RandomName1)
And from 2020-02-15 to 2020-02-17 on second trader (RandomName2)

So I need to join on dates because I need valid trader on that time sequence.

Comment: Why do you need to join on dates? surely ean is enough Please publish your desired output

Comment: because TRADER is changing between dates = ie. one trader from 2020-01-01 to 2020-02-15 and another from  2020-02-16 to 2020-02-17 and ean is from 2020-01-01 to 2020-02-17. So 2 traders in this time sequence.

Comment: Trader = dealer? and I don't see how changing dealer makes any difference since there is no new ean for 123456 to cover the prices on apples after 2020-02-15 in table 2..

Comment: yes. Thanks I edited questions with simple next ID in table with  another dealer in one time sequence from table 2

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the JOIN conditions on `date_from` and `date_to` are filtering out the row with the EAN value "123456".

If you don't need the date conditions, you can remove them from the JOIN an you will have all EAN rows in the result.

Comment: I edited questions for information about why i need date time join